# YouTubePlayer(View) keeps pausing in landscape

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm building a app that contains a YouTubePlayerView and YouTubePlayer, it works well in Portrait, Fullscreen-landscape but not landscape. It keeps pausing every second after I press play. The buffer shows it is fully loaded on some videos, yet it keeps pausing.
I tested it on Android 2.2.2 and Android 4.1.2 with the latest version of the YouTube app.
This happens in all player styles.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the size of the YoutubePlayer view is atleast 200x110 dp like descriped in the [Youtube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView). Sounds like it doesn't meet those requirements when in landscape mode.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the problem, the player was to big for the screen once in landscape

Answer (score 0):

I were facing same issues. but i am just using below concept it will work for me.

1. take a linear layout in your activity layout xml.

> ```
>     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_youtube_player"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_weight="1"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_55sdp"
>     android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_55sdp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_55sdp"
>     android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_55sdp"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     />
> ```

2. Take a layout in which youtube player will be define layout_youtube_video_view_detail.xml.

> ```
>     <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/you_tube_player_view" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"/>
> ```

3. In your activity inside onCreate() inflate youtube xml and add in your layout by code:

`LinearLayout llYoutubePlayer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_youtube_player);
    youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_youtube_video_view_detail, null);
    llYoutubePlayer.addView(youTubePlayerView);
    youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.you_tube_player_view);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(AppConstants.YOU_TUBE_API_KEY, this);`

4. in your onInitializationSuccess please pass video id.

`@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    /** Start buffering **/
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.loadVideo(videoId);
    }
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            youTubePlayerView.refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }, AppConstants.DELAY_500);
}`

I hope it will work.