# Pausing youtube video after 1-2 seconds

Tags: android, youtube

I am using an Youtube Player api for playing youtube videos in my application. Video start playing and pausing after 1-2 seconds

I created Video Fragment and ViewGroup. Subsequently I create some youtobe videoview.

VideoFragment

```
public static final class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements
        OnInitializedListener
{

    private YouTubePlayer player;
    private String videoId;

    public static VideoFragment newInstance()
    {
        return new VideoFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initialize(Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        if (player != null)
        {
            player.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void setVideoId(String videoId)
    {
        if (videoId != null && !videoId.equals(this.videoId))
        {
            this.videoId = videoId;
            if (player != null)
            {
                player.cueVideo(videoId);
            }
        }
    }

    public void pause()
    {
        if (player != null)
        {
            player.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
            boolean restored)
    {
        this.player = player;
        if (!restored && videoId != null)
        {
            player.cueVideo(videoId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result)
    {
        this.player = null;
    }

}
```

Function for creating Youtobe videoview

```
private ViewGroup createYouTubePlayer(final VideoData data, final FrameLayout youTubePlayer)
{

    youTubePlayer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            FragmentManager fm = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();

            if (v.getId() == mCurrentYouTubePlayer)
            {
                return;
            }

            VideoFragment fragment = (VideoFragment) fm.findFragmentById(mCurrentYouTubePlayer);
            if (fragment == null)
            {
                fragment = VideoFragment.newInstance();
                fragment.setVideoId(data.srcPath);

                fm.beginTransaction().add(youTubePlayer.getId(), fragment).commit();
                mCurrentYouTubePlayer = v.getId();
            }
            else
            {
                fm.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();

                fragment = VideoFragment.newInstance();
                fragment.setVideoId(data.srcPath);
                fm.beginTransaction().add(youTubePlayer.getId(), fragment).commit();
                mCurrentYouTubePlayer = v.getId();
            }
        }
    });



    return youTubePlayer;
}
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Do you want to pause it after 2 seconds? Or pausing is the actual problem and you don't want it?

Comment: Pausing is the actual problem

Comment: Try check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014087/views-overlayed-above-youtubeplayerfragment-or-youtubeplayerview-in-the-layout-h

Comment: yeah same issue i got it, pls give me solution if u got it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981645/youtubeplayerview-keeps-pausing-in-landscape/39384449#39384449

Comment: Try reducing the targetSdkVersion in your app's build.gradle to 19. I have no idea why but this worked for me when I was experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

It is not possible to add buttons as overlays above the player as specified by Google, otherwise the player will stop:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView

> Note that while videos are playing, this View has a minimum size of
>   200x110 dp. If you make the view any smaller, videos will
>   automatically stop playing. Also, it is not permitted to overlay the
>   view with other views while a video is playing.
>
> This view does not support padding. To achieve the same effect, wrap
>   the view in another ViewGroup or give it margins.

Padding is also not supported on YouTubePlayer.

To overlay your view on video, I will recommend you to use **ExoPlayer**,
It is not part of the android sdk, but it's recommended by google and included in android developer documentation :

http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/

Exoplayer allow you to stream any kind of video, not only Youtubes videos.

It's also good to mention that Exoplayer is used in youtube application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because there is some object above com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView or the video has padding property

Answer (score 0):

if anybody using the Youtube Fragment then use replace in transaction rather than add.

YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.youtube_frame, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
```