# YouTubePlayer sometimes pauses after 1 second on some devices

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I have a very strange problem with both YouTubePlayerView and the YouTubePlayerFragment.

My app is an alarm clock and i want my users to be able to set a youtube video as their alarm.

Here is the alert fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_button_size"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSep"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/white_secondary_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNotificationHourYoutube"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tvSep"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="7:00"
            android:textColor="@color/white_secondary_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAlarmLabelYoutube"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tvSep"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Wake up"
            android:textColor="@color/white_secondary_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/ypvAlert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/half_activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_activity_vertical_margin"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:minHeight="110dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llYoutubeButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnStopAlarmBigYoutube"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_button_size"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_primary_accent"
            android:text="@string/stop_alarm"
            android:textColor="?android:colorBackground"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSnoozeYoutube"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_button_size"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/snooze"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_bold" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the layout xml file of the activity that contains the fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I tested the alarm on 2 smartphones (Nexus 5 and huawei) and on one tablet (Asus). At first i tried to force the app to be on landscape if it is a youtueb alarm by using:

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

The thing is that on the nexus 5 the video is almost always stops after 1 second. If i set an alarm for 2 minutes from now it will play ok for 50% of the attempts, and if i set an alarm for tomorrow morning it always stops after 1 second. On the Huawei it almost always play ok and on the tablet it's 50/50. 
This is the message i get when the video stops:

```
YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. 
The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor 
android.widget.FrameLayout{89c240f V........ ......I. 0,0-0,0}. The 
distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: 
left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 (these should all be positive).
```

I don't have any FrameLayout on the alarm alert fragment but i have a FrameLayout on the activity xml file that contains the fragment so i replaced the FrameLayout with fragment, so the xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/articles_list"
android:name="com.sux.alarmclock.AlarmNotificationFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_alarm_alert_material_youtube" />
```

But i still get the same error message even though now there is not any FrameLayout in the xml. I have interstitial ads in my app so i canceled the ads but the error still occurs.

So i tried to set the activity to portrait instead of landscape and now it's working on the nexus and on huawei most of the times but almost always stops on the tablet after 1 second.

I also noticed that when i include the YouTubePlayerFragment inside my Activity , or when i extend the YouTubeBaseActivity, every time i start the activity, it creates 2 instances of the activity instead of 1, regardless to the flags i add to the intent or the launch mode (I don't know if it has something to do with the issue)

I can play YouTube on WebView using the RTSP links, but in order to extract the RTSP link i need to use this project:
https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor

And the developer told me that they are extracting the RTSP urls through backdoor which might be aganist the Yotube policies.

I want the YouTube player to work on all devices all the times. Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 3):

These are the possible reasons for this issue. Please check the logcat to find out which is your issue

UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY - Other views overlapping with youtube view

PLAYER_VIEW_TOO_SMALL - Youtube view too small

USER_DECLINED_RESTRICTED_CONTENT - Trying to play restricted content

BLOCKED_FOR_APP - Certain videos are blocked for app.

When i had the issue, it was because of UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/scImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <FrameLayout
            andriod:id"@+id/youtube_parent
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The imageview was below the framelayout which had the youtube player. I moved it to the top (**The final, fixed layout is the example above**) and it started to work.(I tried setting the Zindex it didnt help).

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView), be noted that while videos are playing, `View` has a minimum size of 200x110 dp. If you make the `view` any smaller, videos will automatically stop playing. Also, it is not permitted to overlay the view with other views while a video is playing.

Additional reference which might help:

- [Pausing youtube video after 1-2 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015127/pausing-youtube-video-after-1-2-seconds)

  > It is not possible to add buttons as overlays above the player as specified by Google, otherwise the player will stop.
  >
  > Padding is also not supported on YouTubePlayer.
  >
  > To overlay your view on video, I will recommend you to use ExoPlayer, It is not part of the android sdk, but it's recommended by google and included in android developer documentation :
  >
  > http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/
- [Views overlayed above YouTubePlayerFragment or YouTubePlayerView in the layout hierarchy cause playback to pause immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014087/views-overlayed-above-youtubeplayerfragment-or-youtubeplayerview-in-the-layout-h)

  > Overlays on top of any of our YouTube players (including the YouTube Android Player) are not supported. When an overlay is detected, playback stops and the log contains information helpful in debugging the issue. We do support Action Bar overlays, take a look at this demo to learn more: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications#Overlay_ActionBar_Demo.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can see on the xml file that the minimum width and height are already set to 200 * 110dp and that nothing overlay the YouTube player. Also, there is no padding.